# Flask 404'ing on static content I have in an assets directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My project structure looks like this:

```
/project home
app.py
/templates/index.html
/templates/assets
```

and my index.html file has several references to relative stylesheets that look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick-theme.css">
```

Same for various JS files that exist in assets/js. Now when I load the page, I get this error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:5000/assets/js/popper.min.js”. localhost:5000:564:1
```

There are many of these messages and in the python debugger I see:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2019 18:29:16] "GET /assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I tried googling and changing this line in Flask

```
STATIC_URL_PATH = '/templates/assets/' # Where the css is stored
STATIC_FOLDER = '/templates/assets/'
app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_folder=STATIC_FOLDER,
            static_url_path=STATIC_URL_PATH)
```

But still when I click the index.html page in templates its able to load fine with all the CSS and JS and images, but from Flask, its like the CSS is stripped out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure that the *templates* folder is in the *same directory* as your *app.py*:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── assets
```

Then create the Flask instance like this:

```py
STATIC_FOLDER = 'templates/assets'
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder=STATIC_FOLDER)
```

1st, `/templates` and `templates` (without `/`) are 2 different paths. The 1st one refers to a `templates` folder under the root path `/` of your system, which certainly isn't the one you want. The 2nd one refers to a `templates` folder in the same directory, which is the one you want.

2nd, there is no need to specify `static_url_path` if it's just the same as the `static_folder`, because that's the [default behavior](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask) ("Defaults to the name of the `static_folder` folder").

Then, in your HTML files, instead of hardcoding the paths to the assets folder, let Flask build the URL for you. See the [Static Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files) section of the Flask docs:

> To generate URLs for static files, use the special `'static'` endpoint
>   name:
>
> `url_for('static', filename='style.css')`

By default, it will look for static files under the *static* folder (ex. *static/style.css*) because that it is the [default value for the `static_folder` parameter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask) in the `Flask` constructor. When you set it to *templates/assets*, Flask will use that and will automatically build the correct URL with `url_for`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/slick.css') }}">
```

**Note**:
Make sure that, when testing the loading of static files, clear your browser's cache first or test your app on private/incognito mode of your browser, to force re-downloading of static files.

Comment: Thanks Gino I ended up doing something similar by trial and error with the url_for expression and got it working an hour after posting this question. This answer has a lot of useful information I didn't know though and is the right answer so im selecting it as best answer